# My WlanRegisterNotification callback is only working when the callback is static

Tags: c++, callback

I have been struggling for days to figure out the probably obvious reason why i cant get my code to compile.

I have a class (based on wxThread) where the callback is defined:

-- Header file --

```
class TestClass : public wxThread
{
private:
     static void WlanNotification(WLAN_NOTIFICATION_DATA *wlanNotifData, VOID *p); 
};
```

-- Code file --

I call the WlanRegisterNotification function, that needs the above callback function as a parameter:

```
dwResult = WlanRegisterNotification(hClient, WLAN_NOTIFICATION_SOURCE_ALL, true, (WLAN_NOTIFICATION_CALLBACK) WlanNotification, this, 0, &dwPrevNotif);
```

This compiles and works fine, but the problem is the function is marked as static, so i cant access my non static stuff from the callback (which i need for other reasons).

I have tried every single combination i can think of to pass in the callback as non static:

-- Header file --

```
void WINAPI WlanNotification(PWLAN_NOTIFICATION_DATA data, PVOID context);
```

-- Code file --

```
dwResult = WlanRegisterNotification(hClient, WLAN_NOTIFICATION_SOURCE_ALL, true, (WLAN_NOTIFICATION_CALLBACK)WlanNotification, this, 0, &dwPrevNotif);
```

i just get:

- error C2660: 'WlanRegisterNotification' : function does not take 6
  arguments
- error C2440: 'type cast' : cannot convert from 'overloaded-function' 
  to 'WLAN_NOTIFICATION_CALLBACK'

I'm thinking its related to the typedef somehow:

```
typedef VOID (WINAPI *WLAN_NOTIFICATION_CALLBACK) (PWLAN_NOTIFICATION_DATA, PVOID);
```

I have tried googling for examples of using the WlanRegisterNotification function, but none of the examples i could find is calling it from a class, which is what seems to be an issue here, so i'm really lost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A non-static class method has a hidden `this` parameter that the callback is not expecting let alone know how to fill in.  That is why you cannot use it as a callback unless you either 1) use `static` to remove that parameter, or 2) create a thunk to use as the actual callback and then have it internally  delegate to a non-static class method.  Remember that the Windows API is designed for C, not C++.  There are no classes or implicit `this` pointers in C.

In this case, a static callback can access non-static members of your class because you are explicitly passing the object's `this` pointer as the `pCallbackContext` of `WlanRegisterNotification()`, which is then passed as-is to the `context` of the callback:

```
class TestClass : public wxThread
{
private:
     static VOID WINAPI WlanNotification(PWLAN_NOTIFICATION_DATA wlanNotifData, PVOID context); 
};

VOID WINAPI TestClass::WlanNotification(PWLAN_NOTIFICATION_DATA wlanNotifData, PVOID context)
{ 
    TestClass *pThis = (TestClass*) context;
    // use pThis-> to access non-static members as needed..
}
```

```
// get rid of the typecast when passing the callback. If it does
// not compile, then it is not declared in a compatible manner...
dwResult = WlanRegisterNotification(hClient, WLAN_NOTIFICATION_SOURCE_ALL, TRUE, &WlanNotification, this, 0, &dwPrevNotif);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the very good explanation, now it works perfectly with the changes you wrote, and now i know how to deal with this the next time the issue arises :)